# PHP multidimensional array to variables

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok I am getting info from poloniex API.

It comes back as an array like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 357988064 [currency] => DOGE [rate] => 0.00008000 [amount] => 3134.03982846 [duration] => 0.25540000 [interest] => 0.06403308 [fee] => -0.00960496 [earned] => 0.05442812 [open] => 2017-05-30 23:12:09 [close] => 2017-05-31 05:19:55 ) [1] => Array ... and so on
```

Now I am trying to get each element of the array into some sort of variable to use later.

So something like this:

```
$id=[id] 
$currency=[currency]
$rate=[rate]
$amount=[amount]
$duration=[duration]
$interest=interest]
$fee=fee]
$earned=[earned]
$open=[open]
$close=[close]
```

I want to  put them into a mysqli DB

This is what i am using right now:

```
if (!$return) {
    echo "No Data";
    print_r($return);
} else {
    $arrlength=count($return);
    echo "this many results: " .$arrlength. "<br><br>";
    foreach($return as $x=>$x_value)
      {

        echo $return[0][0]. ": Currency: " .$return[0][1]. ". Rate: " .$return[0][2]. " Duration: " .$return[0][3]. " Interest: " .$return[0][4]. " Fee: " .$return[0][5]. " Earned: " .$return[0][6]. " Opened: " .$return[0][7]. " Closed: " .$return[0][8]. "<br>";

        //  insert into Database here
      }

    // print_r($return);
}
```

And all it is returning is

```
 : Currency: . Rate: Duration: Interest: Fee: Earned: Opened: Closed:
```

I am a newbie with arrays but i have had success with api's with Json this is 1st  with Arrays.

Been tinkering for a few days with this and i just cant get the right combo

EDIT:
for anyone who can use this info i went the answer below and to display it on one line i went like this.

```
if (!$return) {
    echo "No Data";
    //print_r($return);
} else {
    $arrlength=count($return);
    echo "this many results: " .$arrlength. "<br><br>";

foreach($return as $x=>$x_value){
    extract($x_value);
    echo $id."   " .$currency."   " .$rate."   " .$duration."   " .$interest."   " .$fee."   " .$earned."   " .strtotime($open)."   " .strtotime($close)."<br>";
    //  insert into Database here
    }
    // print_r($return);
}
```

Comment: Check - http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
foreach($return as $x=>$x_value)
{
foreach($x_value as $key=>$value){

    echo @$key.":".$return[$x][$key]."<br>";

    //  loop the insert query only columnname and values here
}
//or
extract($x_value);
//echo $id.':'.$currency......;
echo "insert into table_name set id='".$id."', currency='".$currency."',
      rate='".$rate."', amount='".$amount."', duration='".$duration."',
     interest='".$interest."', fee='".$fee."', earned='".$earned."'";
}
```

Comment: this is not working it is showing like this 
` id:358010478: Currency: 358010478. Rate: 358010478 Duration: 358010478 Interest: 358010478 Fee: 358010478 Earned: 358010478 Opened: 358010478 Closed: 358010478
id:DOGE: Currency: DOGE. Rate: DOGE Duration: DOGE Interest:`

Comment: hey now that is very close!  but to put into the DB i need it split by the ID and i would love to read it one line

Comment: question how could this work if i am looking for variable to a certain key?  like above if i just want for  [0]  or say [76] ?

Comment: when you are `extract` that will convert key as variable ...If you have number then you can use `foreach` for better understanding

Comment: not sure im following?   could you show an example  where i know i want the varaibles from say [0] or maybe [98]

Comment: what `say [0]` here ..say is the array name?

Comment: yep like in example above you see it is [0] and [1]  i just cut it off at 1 above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147774/discussion-between-dynamite-media-and-lalithkumar).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Extract` to convert array key to variable.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: please avoid link only is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try php `extract()` method.

```
// Static Array.
$data = array();
$data[0]['id']='357988064';
$data[0]['currency']='DOGE';
$data[0]['rate']='0.00008000';
$data[0]['amount']='3134.03982846';
$data[0]['duration']='0.25540000';
$data[0]['interest']='0.06403308';
$data[0]['fee']='-0.00960496';
$data[0]['earned']='0.05442812';

$data[1]['id']='314564564';
$data[1]['currency']='DOGE TWo';
$data[1]['rate']='0.00124564';
$data[1]['amount']='23135.153';
$data[1]['duration']='0.455254';
$data[1]['interest']='0.5456';
$data[1]['fee']='-0.5625';
$data[1]['earned']='0.5464';

// Loop and extract data.
foreach($data as $k=>$var){
    extract($var);
    $ins = "insert into `table_name` set `id`='".$id."', `currency`='".$currency."', `rate`='".$rate."', `amount`='".$amount."', `duration`='".$duration."', `interest`='".$interest."', `fee`='".$fee."', `earned`='".$earned."'";
    echo $ins."<br />";
}
```

**Output**

```
insert into `table_name` set `id`='357988064', `currency`='DOGE', `rate`='0.00008000', `amount`='3134.03982846', `duration`='0.25540000', `interest`='0.06403308', `fee`='-0.00960496', `earned`='0.05442812'
insert into `table_name` set `id`='314564564', `currency`='DOGE TWo', `rate`='0.00124564', `amount`='23135.153', `duration`='0.455254', `interest`='0.5456', `fee`='-0.5625', `earned`='0.5464'
```

Comment: that would work but i its a api and could come back with 300 plus results,  thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

PHP Multidimensional array to variable

```
<?php
$array = Array
(
    'success' => '1',
    'result' => array(
        'id' => '12345678ABCDEXXX',
        'userid' => '2950',
        'system_user_id' => '76',
        'coin' => 'TRX',
        'amount' => '11.110000',
        'feePercent' => '0',
        'feeAmount' => '0',
        'memoTag' => '',
        'networkFee' => '0',
        'address' => 'TESTADDRESSHERE',
        'confirmations' => '0',
        'callBackUrl' => 'www.xyz.com/test',
        'transactionStatus' => 'WaitingForTransaction',
        'transactionType' => 'Deposit',
        'createdOn' => '1643692929',
        'modifiedOn' => '1643692929',
        'expiredon' => '1644988929',
        'description' => 'This is description'
    )
);

function extractMultidimentional($array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)){
            extractMultidimentional($value);
        }else{
            global ${$key};//Set as global 
            ${$key} = $value;//Assign with its value
        }
    }
}

extractMultidimentional($array);


// Now you can call each key as a variable
echo $success;//1
echo $system_user_id;//76
echo $expiredon;//1644988929
```

If you have multidimensional array and those have same key then the variable will store last array value

Answer (score -1):

You can convert associative array to variebles like bellow code:

```
$list = array( 'var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2' );
foreach ( $list as $key => $value ) {
   $$key = $value; 
}
echo $var1; //prints 'value1'
echo $var2; //prints 'value2'
```

It's a simple way and work very well

Comment: how does that work with my code above?  im confused sorry

Comment: i tried it and does not do anything i need it to do.  thanks

Comment: 1. `$list` is not a replica of the sample input 2. Variable variables are a symptom of poor code design. 3. This answer is poorly explained to people who would benefit from it.  Ultimately, I would not recommend that anyone use this approach. <- this is why I have downvoted this answer and voted to delete the post.